# iOS Accessibility - Voice over repeating the same UI elements again in a loop

Tags: ios, accessibility

I am new to accessibility, I have a simple table view which has a custom cell with some labels and text field, I have also set the order of elements to be read by self.contentView.accessibilityElements in awake from nib method. But when I run the app in voice over mode, some elements are repeated multiple times in a loop this happen when i swap 2 fingers from bottom to top , How can i stop this or is this a expected behaviour ?.

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()

// Initialization code

            self.contentView.accessibilityElements = [headerlabel, Okbutton, nameTextField]

        }
```

Comment: To clarify, the code you have posted is part of the tableview cell itself right?

Comment: To clarify, removing `contentView` did the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works and reads everything below the cell as well, after a 2 finger swipe up.

```
self.accessibilityElements = [headerLabel, okButton, nameTextField]
```